# How to change WhatsApp notification & SMS tone for iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, ringtones

Does anyone know how to change WhatsApp notification & SMS tone for iOS 7 (on iPhone 5S)?

I would like to use a ringtone such as Chinese music uploaded from phone or apps instead of using the default tone for WhatsApp.

Answer (score 5):

This feature has been added and can be found in Whatsapp -> Settings -> Notifications. SMS tone is in the same place as always, Settings -> Sounds -> Text tone.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I can verify that on iOS 7 with the latest version of Whatsapp at the time of my post (May 2015) that this works.

Answer (score 2):

This is currently no way to change that notification sound. This feature would need to be enabled by the developers themselves. You can try requesting this feature by emailing them. [Here's the link](http://www.whatsapp.com/contact/).

Answer (score 0):

I've just done it on my wife's phone. Open whatsapp - the app, click the setting cog (bottom right), notifications, message notifications - new message..select your tone! No jail breaking, no fancy anything

Comment: Could you expand your answer? How exactly does this solve the problem?

Comment: what is winscp cause i got my own notification i would like to use on whatsapp

Comment: Interesting... actually this was the best answer, and the only right answer on this page: to change the tone, you have to do it from within the app's Settings pane, not the iPhone's settings app.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, but unfortunately your phone has to be jailbroken. 
And once you SSH into your phone via Putty or something similar its easy here is a complete tutorial
http://mythreebytes.wordpress.com/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score -1):

I am afraid you are mistaken. The feature is blocked in the latest whatsapp version for IOS.

Comment: It's still there for me, are you sure?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post once you have sufficient reputation.